# What is best practice to inject IOptions in to my ICollectionService Extension?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a library class that accepts an IOptions parameter in its constructor as below:

```
public class MyClass{
   MySetting _setting;
   public MyClass(MySetting setting){
      _setting = setting;
   }
   public void DoSomeThings(){
      //...
   }
}
```

now I want to create an IServiceCollection Extension to facilitate the setup of my library in user code but I am not certain about the best way to inject MySetting into the Constructor.
I can Rely on users to use this code in their startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySetting"));
```

or I can inject MySetting into my Extention method as a parameter like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMtService<T>(this IServiceCollection services, MySetting setting)
```

Or I can read the appsetting.json file in my extension method and create the setting inside it.
Which one is the best approach and is there any other option that can be better of these?

Answer (score 2):

You can check in more detail from: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options)

**Basic usage:**

Inject IOptions with your config class in your service:

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private readonly MySettings _config;
    public TestService(IOptions<MySettings> config)
    {
        _config = config.Value; // You have the configuration class hire...
    }

    public void TestFunction()
    {
        string name = _config.Name;
        bool isTrue = _config.IsTrue;
        bool isFalse = _config.IsFalse;
    }
}
```

When your config class looks something like this:

```
public class MySettings
{
    public const string ConfigSectionKey = "MySettings";
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrue { get; set; }
    public bool IsFalse { get; set; }
}
```

Registration of your config class to IOptions:

```
builder.Services.Configure<MySettings>(builder.Config.GetSection(MySettings.ConfigSectionKey));
```

And the properties are present in appsettings.json (or where you hold your configuration)

```
{...
  "MySettings": {
    "Name": "Tralalaa",
    "IsTrue": true,
    "IsFalse": false
  }
}
```

Comment: I know how to create IOption<MySetting>, My question is about where is the best approach to Inject this argument into my service?

Comment: I think directly in the constructor, no need for factory it in a config service before, unless you need to fill some specific interface with parameters from MyClass... otherwise via IOptions directly from a constructor, like in the top example